# При setState в ReactJS обновляю лист с фильтрацией, но почему то Изображение остается от предыдущего списка, почему?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

При `setState` в ReactJS обновляю лист с фильтрацией, но почему то Изображение остается от предыдущего списка, почему?

```
{_.map(this.state.filteredEmployees, (employee, code) =>
    <div className="employee-item" key={code} style={{cursor: 'initial'}}>
        <div className="employee-info">
            <EmployeeThumbnailContainer employeeCode={employee.code} employeeFullName={employee.fullname}
                                                                    width={40} height={40}/>
            <div onClick={() => showEmployee(employee.code)}  className="uk-margin-small-left">
                <div className="fullname test1">{employee.fullname}</div>
                <div className="position">{employee.jobPosition}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="department-info">
            <span className="company-name">{employee.companyName}</span>
            <span className="department-name">{employee.departmentName}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="employee-birthday">{moment(employee.birthDate).format("DD MMMM")}</div>
        <div className="action-icons">
            <div style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} className={classnames({
                "hidden": typeof employee.isBirthdayToday !== 'undefined' && !employee.isBirthdayToday && !showBirthday,
                "birthday-icon": showBirthday,
                "life-bi-icon-double-arrow": typeof employee.eventType !== 'undefined' && employee.eventType !== 'Прием',
                "life-bi-icon-user-plus": typeof employee.eventType !== 'undefined' && employee.eventType === 'Прием'
            })}
                     onClick={(e) => {
                         e.stopPropagation();

                         this.props.toggleCongratulateEmployee({
                             employee: employee,
                             type: typeof employee.isBirthdayToday !== 'undefined' && employee.isBirthdayToday || employee.eventType
                         });
                     }}/>
        </div>
    </div>
)}
```

А вот одно из фильтрации

```
case 'Все':
    this.setState({
        filteredEmployees: unWritable,
        activeFilter: false
    });
break;
```

Comment: не оч круто использовать русские ключи)

Comment: а о каком изображении идет речь? в коде, в каком месте он меняться должен?

Comment: EmployeeThumbnailContainer  Это вызов аватарок по коду пользователя

Comment: Туда каждый раз новый запрос по коду уходит методом но к сожалению даже при получения response он все равно при setState показывает старые авартарки но все остальное меняется ! даже если нажать на авартарку он откроет новое фото  нужного человека

Comment: Добавьте код компонента `EmployeeThumbnailContainer`, скорее всего он не ре-рендерится